# Changing user's response status for future events using Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a recurring event created in Google Calendar.
How can I accept all the future events ("this and following events") for a guest using Google Calendar API?

I found only examples where `responseStatus` was set for the entire event (all instances) or for a single instance.
I can't follow the solution from: https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents#modifying_all_following_instances, because only event's creator is allowed to modify recurring rule of the original event - I have access only to guest's account.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot update the `recurrence` rules of the main event, you can do the following instead:

- Using the `eventId` of the recurring event, call [Events: instances](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances) to list all the instances of the event.
- Filter the returned instances according to their `start` and/or `end` dates, so that past events are removed from the list.
- For each of the remaining events, call [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) in order to update the attendee's [responseStatus](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#attendees.responseStatus), [this status being](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing#private_event_properties):

> The only event change that is propagated from attendees back to the organizer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The proposed solution may lead to creating multiple exceptions. That's something I'd like to avoid. Especially in a case I had to deal with infinite recurring event it would be very inefficient.

Comment: @MarcinM While this solution can lead to exceptions, I don't think there's a better way to do this, since modifying the `recurrence` rules of the main event is not possible if you are not the event creator. This makes it impossible to update many (but not all) instances of the event at once. Regarding the infinite recurring event, I'd consider filtering out not only according to a minimum date (today?) but to a maximum date (far away in the future) so that you get a finite number of instances.